# How to create a map in Google Api with multiple info windows & images?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map that has a polyline with multiple info windows. I want the info windows to include an image ( a different image for each info window) and have a click through url. I've plotted the markers (with urls) and the infowindows, but I cannot get the image to pop up (in the infowindow).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html,
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
  // Styles a map in night mode.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 38.6530169, lng: -90.3835485},
    zoom: 6,
    styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{ color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill',stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{ 'visibility': 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{ color: '#c9b2a6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          stylers: [{'visibility': 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{ color: '#dcd2be'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.province',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'on'},{weight: '1.5'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'landscape.natural',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry.fill',
          stylers: [{ color: '#a5b076'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.icon',
          stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.local',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.line',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
        }
        ]
    });

var locations = [
['August 20, 1832',40.423731,-83.8944137, 3,'dunihue.jpg','www.google.com'],
['September 20, 1832', 40.1489329, -84.3119643, 2],
['October 1, 1832', 39.7520154,-85.603323, 1],
];

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 var marker, i;
 var markers = new Array();

 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
 map: map
 });

markers.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = marker.url;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {

var html = '<h4>' + locations[i][0] + '</h4>';
html += '<img src="' + locations[i][4] + '" />';

infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
}

var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 40.423731, lng: -83.8944137},
      {lat: 40.1489329, lng: -84.3119643},
      {lat: 40.1066821, lng: -84.6497071},
      {lat: 39.8379723, lng: -84.958815},
      {lat: 39.7797003, lng: -86.2728364},
      {lat: 39.6415502, lng: -86.8738581},
      {lat: 39.4650324, lng: -87.4433594},
      {lat: 38.9809128, lng: -89.143966},
      {lat: 36.8811974, lng: -94.9064899}
];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#340684',
      strokeOpacity: .5,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=AIzaSyBI8ub80FYP5f06rn2yxwNgJW55L3NEOlM&v=3&callback=initMap">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no "map" in the posted code.  Please describe the issue or error you are encountering and post a [mcve] that demonstrates that issue.

Comment: I've added the complete code.  I've plotted the markers (with urls) and the info windows, but I cannot get the image to appear (in the info window).

Answer (score 1):

When you set the content in the info window, you are only setting the date.

infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);

Try setting it to the html you created, i.e.

infowindow.setContent(html);

Comment: Thank you for your help.